# OpenCV Morphological Skeleton?

Tags: ros, opencv, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the Skeleton morphological operation doesn't exist in OpenCV.  If correct, how do you implement it?  And is there a good reason it isn't in there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10398/opencv-morphological-skeleton?/) by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 422 on 2011-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-06-27**:
Posted.  Maybe I'll get lucky?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-06-27**:
You might post this to the opencv mailing list, as it is more of an OpenCV question than a ROS one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered on opencv mailing list http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Morphological-Skeletonization-td6524496.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0